# How to highlight one part of a tableview cell in swift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have two clicks of gesture recognizer in my tableview cell to access different storyboards.
My second click is in the extreme right of my cell and I want when I click on it to just highlight that button and not the whole cell which includes the other button

**So my question is :** how to separate highlights of different clicks in a tableview cell ?

Comment: Why don’t you just add another view with the size you wanna have and if you click on it, you just change the background color (highlight) of that view?

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the

`tableView.allowsSelection = false`

You can add two views in the cell and add tap

```
func setAccessoryViewTapGestures() {
    var tapGestureforLeftAccesoryView = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapGestureforLeftAccesoryView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftAccessoryViewTapped(_:)))
    tapGestureforLeftAccesoryView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGestureforLeftAccesoryView.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    leftAccessoryView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureforLeftAccesoryView)
    leftAccessoryView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    var tapGestureforRightAccesoryView = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapGestureforRightAccesoryView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightAccessoryViewTapped(_:)))
    tapGestureforRightAccesoryView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGestureforRightAccesoryView.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    rightAccessoryView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureforRightAccesoryView)
    rightAccessoryView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Here `rightAccessoryView` and `leftAccessoryView` are the view in the cell

```
@objc private func leftAccessoryViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  // Add code to highlight the view
}

@objc private func rightAccessoryViewTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Add code to highlight the view
}
```

I think this helps

Comment: i deleted the  lines  tapGestureforRightAccesoryView.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureforRightAccesoryView.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1 because the default is 1 anyway